# Markdown editor multiple lists in questions or answers

Tags: support, markdown, editor

I have just tried to write an answer that involved writing a couple of ordered lists that reset to "1" for each list (lists of steps to carry out).

However, I couldn't help but notice that whenever I added a new list item (as that's all that's available on the markdown editor) to start a new set of steps (i.e. begin from list item 1 again) that all the steps would begin counting from the original list (e.g. if section 1 had 3 steps then the new section would start from step 4).

I cannot find any control of where to start or stop a list (to break the numbering, one might say). Nor can I find a HTML editor button (to close the preceding OL or UL).

Is there such a control and I've completely missed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use HTML to create the lists. Providing there is a break between the lists, you can restart numbering using standard Markdown.

I use an empty HTML comment as a break: `<!-- -->`

1. First
2. Second

1. First again
2. Second again

```
1. First
2. Second

<!-- -->

1. First again
2. Second again
```

---

This also works with paragraph lists:

1. First
2. Second

1. First again
2. Second again

```
1. First

2. Second

<!-- -->

1. First again

2. Second again
```

Comment: This is very embarrassing... I've just gone to answer another question and the list buttons worked as expected... if I added a new line of text (as a header, for example) the new list item button started from 1... quite odd! Thank you so much for the answer, though...

Comment: By the way, you did use HTML in your example; that comment tag in the middle is what I was saying at the end of my answer: you need a break in the middle.

Comment: @Dopapp I said there's no need to "use HTML *to create the lists*". The lists themselves can be standard Markdown, without resorting to writing the HTML yourself. Apologies if that was unclear.

Answer (score 2):

**I say this in advance: this part of my question is more fitting for SO but it does answer the question.**

As you probably know, you can embed some simple HTML in your questions. You can use `<a href=[URL]></a>` tags, for links, `<b></b>` for bold text, and a good number of other tags. Two of these tags are the `<ol></ol>` and `<li></li>` tags as, from what I understand from your question, you already know about.

Here is an example of what you can do using HTML:

**HTML:**

```
<ol>
    <li>Thing 1</li>
    <li>Thing 2</li>
    <li>Thing 3</li>
</ol>

<!-- By closing the list using </ol>, you are ending the ordered list. It does not go past the end tag. BTW, this is a comment tag -->

<ol>
    <li>Thing 1 again</li>
    <li>Thing 2 again</li>
    <li>Thing 3 again</li>
</ol>
```

Output:

> First part of ordered list:
>
> 1. Thing 1
> 2. Thing 2
> 3. Thing 3
>
> Second part of ordered list:
>
> 1. Thing 1 again
> 2. Thing 2 again
> 3. Thing 3 again

If I understand your question correctly, then This should be what you're looking for.

Alternatively, you can do this:

> 1. Thing 1.1
> 2. Thing 2.1

Necessary break.

> 1. Thing 1.2
> 2. Thing 2.2
>
> A break can also be the separation using the end of a block/this line or text is not a necessary line break.

1. Item
2. Item 2

If you have any issues with any of this or if this is not what you're looking for just tell me in the comments and I'll fix it accordingly.

I hope this helps!